# setMargins method is not working on Android 6

Tags: android

The following code works on Android 9.0, but not on Android 6.0. I haven't tested the other versions yet. What might be the matter here?

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setSingleLine(true);
btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_button_locked));
btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setTextSize(18);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

after setting layout params in button, call `btn.requestLayout();`